# Pyspark date format

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to convert a string into a date format, for this the string format I have is something like this:

```
2021-01-07 11:17:49.385820+00:00
```

and what I am doing is the following:

```
    format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS+ZZ:ZZ"
    level_1_data_df = level_1_data_value_df\
        .select(
        "level_1_data.*"
        ).withColumn("time2", to_timestamp(col("time"), format))
```

but the result of the new field is null, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do

```
.withColumn("time2", to_timestamp(col("time")))
```

or, equivalently,

```
.withColumn("time2", col("time").cast("timestamp"))
```

because your timestamp has a standard format. No need for specifying its format.